# Javascript Generating pagination numbers

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm trying to generate pagination buttons.

I want the buttons to look like this:

- **1**, 2, 3 ... 7
- **2**, 3, 4 ... 7.
- **3**, 4, 5 ... 7.
- **4**, 5, 6 ... 7.
- **5**, 6, 7.
- 5, **6**, 7.
- 5, 6, **7**.

The bold number is the selected page, 7 is the highest page.

My current function generates this up until the point where you're on the last 3 pages.

```
[1, 2, 3, "...", 7]
[2, 3, 4, "...", 7]
[3, 4, 5, "...", 7]
[4, 5, 6, "...", 7]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7]
[7]
```

What I want it to look like:

```
[1, 2, 3, "...", 7]
[2, 3, 4, "...", 7]
[3, 4, 5, "...", 7]
[4, 5, 6, "...", 7]
[5, 6, 7]
[5, 6, 7]
[5, 6, 7]
```

**Javascript**:

```
var test = function (count, current) {
    this.pageCountArray = [];

    var shownPageNumbers = 3;


    for (var i = current; i <= count; i++) {
        if (this.pageCountArray.length < shownPageNumbers) {
            this.pageCountArray.push(i);
        }
        else {
            this.pageCountArray.push('...');
            this.pageCountArray.push(count);
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(this.pageCountArray);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
test(7, 1);
test(7, 2);
test(7, 3);
test(7, 4);
test(7, 5);
test(7, 6);
test(7, 7);
```

```js
console.clear();
var test = function (count, current) {
    this.pageCountArray = [];

    var shownPageNumbers = 3;


    for (var i = current; i <= count; i++) {
        if (this.pageCountArray.length < shownPageNumbers) {
            this.pageCountArray.push(i);
        }
        else {
            this.pageCountArray.push('...');
            this.pageCountArray.push(count);
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(this.pageCountArray);
  
  document.write(JSON.stringify(this.pageCountArray))
}

test(7, 1);
test(7, 2);
test(7, 3);
test(7, 4);
test(7, 5);
test(7, 6);
test(7, 7);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are populating your array only from `current` to `count`. So, when you get to values for `current` that are above `count - (shownPageNumbers - 1)`, you need to have the for loop start from `count - (shownPageNumbers - 1)` instead of just `current`, in order to show the correct amount of page numbers.

You could add an if statement before the for loops checking if (current > (count - (shownPageNumbers - 1)) and update current to that, or in your for loop set i = min(current, (count - (shownPageNumbers - 1))

Comment: I realise the issue, I'm asking what a good solution to this problem is.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You could add an if statement before the for loops checking `if (current > (count - (shownPageNumbers - 1))` and update current to that, or in your for loop set `i = min(current, (count - (shownPageNumbers - 1))`

Comment: Could you add that to the answer please.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I would implement it:

```
function pageNumbers(count, current) {
    var shownPages = 3;
    var result = [];
    if (current > count - shownPages) {
        result.push(count - 2, count - 1, count);
    } else {
        result.push(current, current + 1, current + 2, '...', count);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/x474jtsd/